# Fuzzy search by default in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, search, customization, kibana, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to make some fuzzy search in kibana using their IHM (ideally by default). I know how to do such a request in the DEV TOOLS section. The problem is to have that option by default. Is it possible? I'd like also to save  all the requests that I entered (by default).

Please find below the search I try to incorporate and get the results.

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
       "fuzzy" : { "NOM" : "COUT" }
    }
}
```

PS: I know that there is a Lucene Syntax for sophisticated requests.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: what do you mean by have that option by default? can you elaborate please!

Comment: I mean that when i'm searching for example children, I can type shildrene or shild reune etc.. So by default, I mean that on the discover search, i want to type the word + or - the errors (phonetics, orthography etc...). I guest that it was possible to include a fuzzy query from elasticsearch to kibana but maybe it's too complicated..